# Custom BasePage causing design view to break

Tags: visual-studio-2010, windows-phone-7, inheritance, windows-phone-7.1

I was getting fed up with typing `this.NavigationService.Navigate(new Uri(page.xaml, UriKind.Relative));`, every time I need to navigate to a different page in my app.

So I've created a custom `BasePage` with a virtual to help with Navigating around my app.

The problem I have is in VS2010, if I have the source and design view open, the design just shows the windows phone background and I get some blue wiggly lines right from the top to the bottom of my xaml and messages along the lines of x isn't supported. This happens on any page that I have set up to Inherit from my custom BasePage.

However, if I run the application on my Windows Phone or in the Emmulator it will work.

Does anyone have any suggestions of what I could try to keep my Design view working whilst apply my custom base, or if I have missed something off?

A slightly cut down version of my BasePage is:

```
public class BasePage : PhoneApplicationPage
{
    public virtual void NavigateTo(string pageName, params Tuple<string,string>[] queryString)
    {
      // Code to perform this.NavigationService.Navigate
    }
}
```

**EDIT 2011-08-16**

Part of this base page overrides the `PhoneApplicationPage`'s `OnNavigatedTo` method, in which I perform a security check to see if:

1. security has been enabled
2. User is logged in

If the security is enabled but the user is not logged in, they are immediately redirected to a Login Page.

I found this useful as I don't then have to add any code to existing or new pages to handle this, so long as they derive from the `BasePage`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wouldn't recommend using a BasePage for this. Instead, simply add your `NavigateTo` method in the `App.xaml.cs` file, as a static method.

```
public static void NavigateTo(string pageName, params Tuple<string,string>[] queryString)
{
  // Code to perform this.NavigationService.Navigate
}
```

Also, remember to wrap the call to `.Navigate` in `Dispatcher.BeginInvoke` so all transition effects are properly executed.

And as a bonus tip: Don't use the designer in Visual Studio. Instead, set the 'default editor'  for XAML files to be the "Source Code" editor, so the designer is never opened. This makes Visual Studio much more stable.

If you want a designer, you should get Microsoft Expression (Blend)

Comment: Thanks for the help, I probably should have added I use an `OnNavigateTo` override so that I can check on each page if my app has had it's password functionality turned on and then if I am logged in before entering a page. already have expression blend, got the sdk tools too, which is why it is annoying that my BasePage wont return a design

Comment: I've found I cannot put this as a static method as `this.NavigationService.NavigateTo` wont work. NavigationService wont compile in the `Application` class either am I missing something?

Comment: Oh right, yeah, you need to call it on the Current RootVisual of course. `(App.RootVisual As PhoneApplicationFrame).NavigateTo(...)`

Comment: I'll try that out tonight. do you have any suggestion on how I can perform a security check on my pages, or would this be best served again from the `App` as a static method and just call from each page's `OnNavigatedTo`? I've explained in an edit on my question.

Comment: Such checks belongs in your viewmodel, or general application logic. You should rethink your architecture, if your current idea is to check on every page.

Comment: you're probably right, I'll rub my eyes and take another look.